How to find the bathroom fan with unknown location
I live in a Dutch house, and when I moved in the bathroom layout was changed including the location of the ventilator grid.
However even in the original layout I only knew the location of the grid and not the actual fan.
Now the fan died, and I asked someone to come and replace it but they mentioned it could mean breaking the tiled wall quite a bit without guarantee they would break it in the right place.
Now the question:
how to find the location of the fan with minimal risk of unnecessary damage.
Thoughts so far:

Make a little hole and look: This is  not so easy as due to the built in toilet reservoir there is a extra layer of wall, probably the first level would need to be opened quite a bit before being able to check behind the second one
Push up the metal ceiling and try to look over the wall: best guess so far but similar concern as this would not allow for looking behind the original wall
Find it on a document/drawing somewhere: would this kind of non visible detail even be captured, and on what kind of document?
Put 'something' in the pipe behind the grid and find at least how deep the first blockade is: the pipe inside seems a bit fragile so what to put inside that won't rip it, also there is a risk of false positives
Something magical, like a portable xray?
Go via the back of the wall: breaking that side would be even worse

I added a picture with where I think the original fan intake was, but even then the pump may be in a completely different spot.


I recall from another Dutch location question that centralized mechanical ventilation (possibly with heat exchange) has been a thing in building code there for several decades, so it might well be nowhere near the bathroom. Building plans should show the layout, if you can find those on file at some (probably local) government office. Look outside for the vent leaving the house, look in the attic if the house has an attic....

Start by locating the exhaust for that ventilation. Where is it? On the wall of the house? On the roof? Does the path between the intake vent and exhaust make sense? When the fan worked, did you hear it and if so did you locate it? I mean, you can't locate it with precision but you can tell if it's in the attic or in the wall hopefully. Does the house have other vents, central ventilation, and does that still work?

The conduit you describe sounds like this can you confirm? If that is the case it will sag so you won't see the other end, but you can take a broomstick (the non sharp end is important because these flexible ventilation hoses tear easily!) and stick it in to maneuver the conduit and straighten it in order to see a bit further away into it.

Is that some kind of removeable ceiling?

If you search for "endoscope" on a major shopping site you should be able to find one for cheap.  They are basically small cameras (usually less than 10mm dia) on the end of a long, flexible but stiff wire.  You should be able to push it into the ventilation grid, see what is inside, and follow the air channel until you find the fan.  Many endoscopes are several meters in length.
Edit: A couple relevant questions:
A device that can see through hollow wood panel to find a hole in plaster covered wall?
Borescope or Endoscopic Camera Technique

Very nice, found the fan and it also helped me with some other chores where it was hard to see what was going on. I did end up tying it to a stick to get the cam far enough in the right direction
